# How to select row from table based on foreign key value using Hibernate (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to get all rows where kotizacija_id is equal to specified ID. Here's my function in Controller

```
  @GetMapping("/kotizacije_cjenovnik/{id}")
  @Timed
    public List<KotizacijeCjenovnik> getKotizacijeByKotizacijaId(@PathVariable BigInteger id) {
    log.debug("REST request to get Kotizacija : {}", id);
    List<KotizacijeCjenovnik> kotizacija_cjenovnik = kotizacijaCjenovnik.getKotizacijeByKotizacijaId(id);
    return kotizacija_cjenovnik;
}
```

This is my KotizacijeCjenovnikRepository

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Repository
public interface KotizacijeCjenovnikRepository extends 
JpaRepository<KotizacijeCjenovnik, BigInteger> {
@Query(value="select kotizacije_cjenovnik from KotizacijeCjenovnik kotizacije_cjenovnik where kotizacije_cjenovnik.kotizacija.id =:id")
List<KotizacijeCjenovnik> getKotizacijeByKotizacijaId(@Param("id") BigInteger id);

 }
```

And here's model KotizacijeCjenovnik

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "kotizacije_cjenovnik")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class KotizacijeCjenovnik implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "cijena1", nullable = false)
private Double cijena1;

@ManyToOne
private Kotizacija kotizacija;

// jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here, do not remove
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

private Double getCijena1() {
    return cijena1;
}

public KotizacijeCjenovnik cijena1(Double cijena) {
    this.cijena1 = cijena;
    return this;
}

public void setCijena1(Double cijena) {
    this.cijena1 = cijena;
}


public Kotizacija getKotizacija() {
    return kotizacija;
}

public KotizacijeCjenovnik kotizacija(Kotizacija kotizacija) {
    this.kotizacija = kotizacija;
    return this;
}

public void setKotizacija(Kotizacija kotizacija) {
    this.kotizacija = kotizacija;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    KotizacijeCjenovnik kotizacijeCjenovnik = (KotizacijeCjenovnik) o;
    if (kotizacijeCjenovnik.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return Objects.equals(getId(), kotizacijeCjenovnik.getId());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(getId());
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "KotizacijeCjenovnik{" +
        "id=" + getId() +
        ", cijena1=" + getCijena1() +
        ", cijena2=" + getCijena2() +
        ", cijena3=" + getCijena3() +
        "}";
    }
}
```

But when I call function getKotizacijeByKotizacijaId I get the error:

> Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]

My question is how to select row where foreign key is equal to specified value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that **Kotizacija**'s id is **long** and not **BigInteger**, but you may specify the **Kotizacija** directly instead of it **id**.
Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/kotizacije_cjenovnik/{id}")
@Timed
public List<KotizacijeCjenovnik> getKotizacijeByKotizacijaId(@PathVariable BigInteger id) {
    log.debug("REST request to get Kotizacija : {}", id);
    Kotizacija kotizacija = new Kotizacija();
    kotizacija.setId(id);
    List<KotizacijeCjenovnik> kotizacija_cjenovnik = kotizacijaCjenovnik.getKotizacijeByKotizacija(kotizacija);
    return kotizacija_cjenovnik;
}
```

Repository:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Repository
public interface KotizacijeCjenovnikRepository extends 
    JpaRepository<KotizacijeCjenovnik, BigInteger> {
    @Query(value="select kotizacije_cjenovnik from KotizacijeCjenovnik kotizacije_cjenovnik where kotizacije_cjenovnik.kotizacija = :kotizacija")
    List<KotizacijeCjenovnik> getKotizacijeByKotizacija(@Param("kotizacija") Kotizacija kotizacija);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have your id specified as a `Long` inside `KotizacijeCjenovnik` entity but you pass your query a `BigInteger`

Change it from a `BigInteger` to a `Long`

```
@Query(value="select kotizacije_cjenovnik from KotizacijeCjenovnik kotizacije_cjenovnik where kotizacije_cjenovnik.kotizacija.id =:id")
List<KotizacijeCjenovnik> getKotizacijeByKotizacijaId(@Param("id") Long id);
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Also I have to convert id.longValue() like @christoph-j suggested.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Entity` you say that the `id` is of type Long. In your `repository` you say its a BigInteger. You should use `Long` in your repository. For the method it should be

`List<...> findAllByKotizacijeId(Long id);`

While using JPA you dont have to write the query

Answer (score 1):

The error message says, that you use the wrong type. It expects long but you passed in a BigInteger. Try:

```
List<KotizacijeCjenovnik> kotizacija_cjenovnik = kotizacijaCjenovnik.getKotizacijeByKotizacijaId(id.longValue());
```